# Hide left navigation items in SharePoint 2013 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, development

Currently I am displaying items on Quick Launch (Left navigation). These items come from  Navigation Setting

My requirement is to hide some items in the left navigation bar programmatically, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can understand your question try this

```
SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SiteUrl); 

SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();

int i;

for (i = spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Count - 1; i > 0;  i--)
{ 
    spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Delete(spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch[ i ]);
}

spWeb.Update();
```

Comment: Is There any Way To Hide The Navigation Item Because Client Will Need To Show That Item After Some Days And Client Does Not Want To Add Items To Navigation Settings They Are Only Willing To Show And Hide..........

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Left Navigation Items with jQuery. Apply this jQuery on your Master Page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Recent')").parent().hide();
                jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Notebook')").parent().hide();
                jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Documents')").parent().hide();
                jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Site Contents')").parent().hide();
            }); 
</script>
```